# Xcode4 crash makes application build fail

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

my xcode 4 just crashed and I get build errors:

> Unknown type name
>   'SecondViewController'

in the @interface code block:

```
SecondViewController *sms;
```

and

> Property with 'retain' attribute must
>   be object type

in

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) SecondViewController *sms;
```

However I import SecondViewController.h. The same code worked before the crash.

FirstViewController.h: http://pastebin.com/jnPKBny7

SecondViewController.h: http://pastebin.com/2D058ZAK

**Edit: I realized that this error occures because the classes import each other. Can anyone describe why this is wrong?**

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the SecondViewController header file and the file where you are getting these errors?

Comment: Does the SecondViewController.m show up in Project navigator -> first entry/your project -> right window Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have circular imports. I think it's good practice to use forward class declarations with the @class directive whenever possible. For your case:

FirstViewController.h:

```
@class SecondViewController ;
@interface FirstViewController
{
    SecondViewController * _secondViewController ;
}

@property ( nonatomic, retain ) secondViewControlller ;

@end
```

SecondViewController.h:

```
@class FirstViewController ;
@interface SecondViewController
{
    FirstViewController * _firstViewController ;
}

@property ( nonatomic, retain ) firstViewControlller ;

@end
```

Then in your .m files, import the .h files for the classes you are using. The only reasons to import .h files into other .h files are:

- framework imports (i.e. )
- you need to use a protocol